# Getting Errno::ENOMEM: Not enough space when 'getting' a page via Mechanize

Tags: ruby, windows-console, mechanize-ruby

I'm currently trying to follow a tutorial on web scraping and have been receiving a ruby error message "Errno::ENOMEM: Not enough space".  I've found a workaround from http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1063 but I was wondering if there is a more permanent solution.  I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32] and I'm not in a position to update to a new version which I suspect would fix this problem.  The issue only appears when I try to get larger pages.

Current Solution:

```
class String
  def to_2d_array(value)
    unpack("a#{value}"*((size/value)+((size%value>0)?1:0)))
  end
end

class << $stdout
  alias old_write write

  def write(a) 
    a.to_s.to_2d_array(1024).each{|little| old_write little}
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I just edit a file in Ruby where I don't have to type this hack in every time, but have it loaded automatically? The String class or somethiing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix my problem I've added:

```
class String
  def to_2d_array(value)
    unpack("a#{value}"*((size/value)+((size%value>0)?1:0)))
  end
end

class << $stdout
  alias old_write write

  def write(a) 
    a.to_s.to_2d_array(1024).each{|little| old_write little}
  end
end
```

To my irb.rb file after the last end.

Comment: Note this can cause problems depending on your directory when you run irb from the command line. I.E. if your at C:\Users\%USERNAME% it will return a error.